# Android emulator is tiny and doesn't run app

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just downloaded the Android SDK (I'm on OS X 10.8.4). I created a new project with all default settings, and a new virtual device. When I run the project, all I see is a tiny window with a few menu options rather than my App.

[image: see here].

I get no errors from adb:

```
[2014-08-30 17:51:03 - Hello] ------------------------------
[2014-08-30 17:51:03 - Hello] Android Launch!
[2014-08-30 17:51:03 - Hello] adb is running normally.
[2014-08-30 17:51:03 - Hello] Performing com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-08-30 17:51:03 - Hello] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Nexus4.4'
[2014-08-30 17:51:03 - Hello] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus4.4'
[2014-08-30 17:51:12 - Hello] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-08-30 17:51:12 - Hello] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

What is going on?!

Answer (score 1):

That is the Android Wear emulator you are running, not a standard AVD for a phone.

Comment: I set it up using all of the defaults. Which configuration option sets that?

Answer (score 0):

OK, there were two problems:
1. The default installation had only images for Android Wear selected
2. The images require Java 7 SDK and OS X comes with 6 by default.

Steps to fix:
1. Download and install Java 7 SDK.
2. In Android SDK Manager, install Android 4.4.2.
3. Restart Eclipse.
4. Set project Target SDK to 19.
5. Set project Min SDK to >=10.